# DDE using System.Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, .net, automation, dde, command-window

Is it possible to use the .NET System.Windows.Automation namespace and do the equivalent of the old DDE?

My requirement is to read the text inside a command window(which could be a mainframe screen as well) from my .NET Windows Forms application.

Am better off using http://ndde.codeplex.com/ for this purpose?

Comment: Nobody is *ever* better off using DDE.  Is it something a legacy program requires or is it just the only thing you know?

Answer (score 1):

As the author of the said DDE library I emphatically implore you to not use it. It is not that it does not work. It is simply that DDE itself is terrible; possibly the worst interprocess communication protocol **ever**.

What you should do is redirect the standard output stream from the console window. This can be done by setting a new stream via `Console.SetOut`. If the terminal is coming from a mainframe then use the `NetworkStream` class to read from the telnet port.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know System.Windows.Automation does not support DDE.

The last time I had to work with DDE we used a vb6 bridge.